# App occasionally crashes when updating ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, adapter

I believe I have a weird situation where on most occasion my app is working as intended but in other instances it would crash.

I have an `ArrayList` and an `adapter` class that I declare globally and that instantiate inside of my `onCreate`. I populate the `ArrayList` using an `onClickListener` inside of my `MainActivity`. I also have a separate class where I define the objects that I am storing inside of my `ArrayList`. In my MainActivity, I have a `button` that adds an object into my `ArrayList` from user input.

Code that takes user input and stores into `ArrayList`:

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(input1.getText().toString()); //Get input from text box
int sum = num1 + score2;
score2 = sum;
output1.setText("Your score is : " + Integer.toString(sum));

//**** ADD TO ARRAYLIST HERE*********
Score score1 = new Score("Hole Number : " + j, num1);
scoreList.add(score1);
//adapter.setNotifyOnChange();

j++;
input1.setText(""); //Clear input text box
```

Here is my `adapter` class:

```
public class ScoreAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Score> {

private Context mContext;
int mResource;

public ScoreAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Score> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    mContext = context;
    mResource = resource;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    //Get Score info
    String hole= getItem(position).getHolenumber();
    int score=getItem(position).getHolescore();

    //Create the Hole info object
    Score sumscore = new Score(hole, score);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);

    TextView holeNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.holeNum);
    TextView holeScore = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.holeScore);

    holeNumber.setText(hole);
    holeScore.setText(Integer.toString(score));

    return convertView;
}
```

}

I want to note that when I add in `notifyDataSetChanged` in my `onClickListener` method, I get a null object pointer error. This doesn't make sense to me because I am perfectly able to populate my `ListView` otherwise which leads me to think that my `adapter` has a valid reference. I am able to populate my `ArrayList` and also see the objects in my `ListView` populating without the `notifyDataSetChanged`.

```
08-11 19:16:43.322 2522-2522/com.example.ray.sportsapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.ray.sportsapp, PID: 2522
                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.ray.sportsapp.ScoreAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference
                                                                         at com.example.ray.sportsapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:71)
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

I am completely lost, any help would be awesome. Thank you.

`MainActivity` declarations and instantiations:

```
ArrayList<Score> scoreList;
ScoreAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView1);

    scoreList = new ArrayList<>();
    ScoreAdapter adapter = new ScoreAdapter(this, R.layout.item_scores, scoreList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Could you show me the `MainActivity`'s `onClick` code? I saw `java.lang.NullPointerException` in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onCreate method change:

```
ScoreAdapter adapter = new ScoreAdapter(this, R.layout.item_scores, scoreList);
```

to:

```
adapter  = new ScoreAdapter(this, R.layout.item_scores, scoreList);
```

Where `adapter` is a global variable.

#### Explanation:

Unqualified names always refer to innermost enclosing declaration.
That means you instantiated a new local variable `adapter` and not the global variable `adapter` which remained null all the time.